# Scraping with specific criteria when similar classes used in html source

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the 8 instances of x between td tags on the following

```
<th class="first"> Temperature </th>
<td> x </td> # repeated for 8 lines
```

There are however numerous classes on page that are `<th class="first">` The only unique identifier is the string that follows first, in this example Temperature.

Not sure what to add to the following code I am using to create some kind of criteria to scrape for  `<th class="first">` where Temperature (and other strings follow)

```
for tag in soup.find_all("th", {"class":"first"}):
    temps.append(tag.text)
```

Is it a matter of additional code (re.compile?) or should I use something else entirely?

Edit: Html of interest below

```
   <tbody>
```

> ```
> <tr>
>     <th class="first">Temperature</th>
>     <td>x</td>
>     <td>x</td>
>     <td>x</td>
>     <td>x</td>
>     <td>x</td>
>     <td>x</td>
>     <td>x</td>
>     <td>x</td>
> </tr>
> ```

Edit: current code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'c:\program files\firefox\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.bom.gov.au/places/nsw/sydney/forecast/detailed/")

html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, "lxml")

dates = []

for tag in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"toggle"}):
    dates.append(tag.text)

temps = [item.text for item in soup.select('th.first:contains(Temperature) ~ td')]

print(dates)
print(temps)
```

Comment: repeated for 8 lines? Is it like
<th class="first"> Temperature </th>
<td> x </td>
<td> x </td>
<td> x </td>
<td> x </td>
<td> x </td>
<td> x </td>
<td> x </td>
<td> x </td> 
?

Comment: Instead of describing the html of interest, provide it, so that we are on the same page. Moreover, what is the result you want to achieve? Retrieving the text from subsequent `td`'s?

Comment: edited to include HTML. Yep, wanting to retrieve the text (temperatures for x) from subsequent td's

Comment: As you said in the question, if the only unique identifier is the string that follows first, in this example Temperature, why don't you try using `if` condition? For example, `if tag.text == "Temperature":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy with bs4 4.7.1. as you can use the :contains pseudo class with ~ general sibling combinator

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'http://www.bom.gov.au/places/nsw/sydney/forecast/detailed'    
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for table in soup.select('[summary*=Temperatures]'):
    print(table['summary']) #day of reading
    tds = [item.text for item in table.select('.first:contains("Air temperature (°C)") ~ td')] #readings
    print(tds)
```

---

You can get the hours of the readings with:

```
print([item.text.strip() for item in table.select('tr:nth-of-type(1) th')][1:-1])
```

---

Nicely formatted tables add in pandas:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.bom.gov.au/places/nsw/sydney/forecast/detailed'    
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for table in soup.select('[summary*=Temperatures]'):
    print(table['summary'])
    output = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have tried but print returns nothing []. Have attempted other strings in place of Temperature, which share same class(first) such as 'At' but  receive similar results. Have updated original post with current code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

s = '''
    <tr>
        <th class="first">Temperature</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>

'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")

[td.text for td in soup.find('th', string=re.compile("Temperature")).find_next_siblings()]
```

and you get:

```
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```